# blast p-error with making directory

Tags: file-formats

I tried running this command `python blastp.py CmydPro tlr TLR.txt` to extract the query sequence for the target species I'm looking at. However, whenever I try running it always comes up as a blast p error and says there's no directory. I downloaded blastp.py as a file made from my lab's GitHub but I have no idea how to troubleshoot the error since it's not a required directory. I made sure all my directories were correct and that all my files were intact. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error I keep getting:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "blastp.py", line 53, in
blastp_scout = subprocess.Popen(['blastp', '-db', organism_db, '-query', 'temp.fa', '-out', 'blast', '-num_descriptions', '5', '-num_alignments', '0'])
File "/home/dylan_w190/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/home/dylan_w190/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'blastp'
```

These are all the files I have stored in my directory:

```
'$RECYCLE.BIN' 'Genome Files' TLR.txt
'ASM 28112' 'Genome Files (1)' Tham
'ASM 28964' 'Genome Files (2)' Vim
'ASM 3597' 'Genome Files (3)' Xenopus
'ASM 45574' 'Genome Files (4)' blast-2.11.0+
AnoCar Git blastp.py
Chrysemys GopAga get-pip.py
Cliv GopAga2.0-Genome human
CmydPro Halia ls
CmydPro_results.txt LICENCE mouse
Config.Msi Lib ncbi-blast-2.6.0+
CroPor Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh ncbi-blast-2.6.0+-win64.exe
'FASTAs (2)' OpenSSH-Win64 pip
Format Ornitho pvi
GCF_015237465.1_rCheMyd1.pri_genomic.fna PelSin pyzo
GFFs Python setup.py
'GFFs (2)' PythonX temp.fa
GRCh38 README.txt tlr_CmydPro.fa
GRCm38 Rnor tlr_ref.fasta
Gallus 'Rnor - Copy' vs_buildtools__576366542.1609221376.exe
GavGan Scripts vs_community__576366542.1609221376.exe
Gekko 'System Volume Information'
```

There is a windows version. It seems that I already downloaded blast but I need to do this now:

`Command 'blastp' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install ncbi-blast+`

Do you have any idea how to might download this?

I already downloaded blast as a tar file and the 2.11.0+ version. I'm just not sure how to download just ncbi-blast+ on its own.

Comment: That looks like you are using Windows. have you asked the developers if the script you are trying to run is even supposed to work on Windows? Is there a Windows version of blast? That can be launched from the command line?

Comment: Could you please tell us what operating system you're running (e.g. Windows, Mac, Linux)? If Linux, could you please show the output of the command `uname -a`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have blastp in your path. Blast is either not installed on your system or it's just not been added to path right.